# json.loads JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, string

**Os cookies aqui postados, não há validade alguma, portanto, se quiseres fazeres maldade, procure outro**

Tenho esses cookies que salvei utilizando a linguagem PHP

```
["fm=0","_twitter_sess=BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCNndap5qAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlMzkyNWI0OWVlNmIwN2M5MDQ3YzlhZDNkYzI0NmM5NmU6B2lkIiUwNTdh%250AYzUxZDk3NGUyNzE3Zjk1MWVhZGQ4MGM5OTkyZQ%253D%253D--288296a1b6be7e778a80e39cfbccb3004f174869","personalization_id=\"v1_xT6WU1iyhYSZyynU1oTJLw==\"","guest_id=v1%3A155743596488632801","ct0=f28684acf870e0f5a950d29b6feb6f2f","dnt=1","fm=0","ads_prefs=\"HBISAAA=\"","kdt=wdmo4K3PfBZiaRTx6fAXLqfqzNXdlpkHmyCH5FpP","remember_checked_on=1","_twitter_sess=BAh7CiIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCNndap5qAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlMzkyNWI0OWVlNmIwN2M5MDQ3YzlhZDNkYzI0NmM5NmU6B2lkIiUwNTdh%250AYzUxZDk3NGUyNzE3Zjk1MWVhZGQ4MGM5OTkyZToJdXNlcmwrCQDAlp7iWowP--fe26fef739a85a922df20c2c2a89f7d50b988670","twitter_id=\"u=1120370336678199296\"","authenticity_token=76521fd518bdd3bcf98e78f8409fe3853e486f31"]
```

Só que ao usar `json.loads(...)` no Python, ele me retorna:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 332 (char 331)
```

Eu não posso usar `json.loads(r'cookies strings')`, porque está vindo do banco de dados.

creio que o `json_decode` do PHP transforma esses json em outra forma, e como estou migrando de PHP para python, preciso de todos os cookies executáveis no Python, tem alguma forma de reverter isso?

Estou a quase 18 horas tentando resolver e nada.

Meu código no momento és:

```
from json import loads

cookies = '; '.join(str(loads(select_random.cookies)) + ';')    
follow_api = FollowApi()
follow = follow_api.follow(select_me.twitter_id, select_random.csrftoken, cookies)
```

Lembrando que cookies vem do banco de dados.

PS: No PHP funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você está tentando passar cookies para o json.loads certo?

Não sei se isso resolve o problema mas primeiro: o loads não vai funcionar pois o cookie que você citou no inicio da pergunta não tem formato json.

Segundo você vai precisar lidar com as aspas duplas quando elas aparecem repetidamente por exemplo aqui "v1_xT6WU1iyhYSZyynU1oTJLw==\"" pois o python não vai entender essa string.

Terceiro mesmo que o programa não tenha executado até esse ponto você está utilizando a função str() para converter o próprio json após ele ter sido formado o que não faz muito sentido creio que você esteja tentando converter o conteudo de select_random.cookies para ai str para ai sim transforma-lo em um json, então ficaria dessa forma `(loads(str(select_random.cookies))`.